# Changing "src" attribute of an image to another image file?

Tags: javascript, html

This portion of my assignment is instructing me to change the src attribute of a collection of star images to another image file.

I've tried numerous combinations of **removeAttribute()** and **setAttribute()**, but no luck.  I'm probably thinking down the wrong path here.

```
function lightStars () {
   var starNumber = e.target.alt;
   var stars = document.querySelectorAll("span#stars img");
for (var i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
   stars.setAttribute("src", "bw_star2.png");
}
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<label id="ratingLabel" for="rating">Rate this title
           <span id="stars">
           <img src="bw_star.png" alt="1" />
           <img src="bw_star.png" alt="2" />
           <img src="bw_star.png" alt="3" />
           <img src="bw_star.png" alt="4" />
           <img src="bw_star.png" alt="5" /></span>
           <input type="text" name="rating" id="rating" readonly value="" />
</label>
```

The purpose of this function is to color a star when the user moves the mouse pointer over a star image in order to reflect the user’s rating of the book.

I hope I explained this properly.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a *list* of elements. You have to iterate through the list.

Comment: @Pointy are you referring to listing stars[0].setAttribute("src", "bw_star2.png"); .... stars[1].setAttribute("src", "bw_star2.png"); .... and so forth for each image within the loop?

Comment: @randomSoul I've edited and added a portion of the HTML code, does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, I think you just missed to access to each stars array position:

```
function lightStars () {
    var starNumber = e.target.alt;
    var stars = document.querySelectorAll("span#stars img");
    for (var i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
        stars[i].setAttribute("src", "bw_star2.png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lightStars () {
   var starNumber = parseint(e.target.alt);
   var stars = document.querySelectorAll("span#stars img");
   for (var i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
       stars.setAttribute("src", "bw_star2.png");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of imgs, I used `glyphicons`. `querySelectorAll` return list of elements. So in order to change its attribute values you need to iterate over it.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('span');

imgs.forEach((img) => {
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', function()  {
      const ratings = this.getAttribute('data-rating');
      for(let i = 0; i < ratings; i++) {
          imgs[i].setAttribute('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-star');
      }

      for(let j = ratings; j < imgs.length; j++) {
          imgs[j].setAttribute('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label id="ratingLabel" for="rating">Rate this title
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true" data-rating="1"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true" data-rating="2"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true" data-rating="3"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true" data-rating="4"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true" data-rating="5"></span>
        <input type="text" name="rating" id="rating" readonly value="" />
     </label>
```

Comment: I'm not certain the sandbox program Cengage uses will recognize the correct code pattern if I change them?

Comment: You can add images. I did not had images and that is the reason behind adding glyphicons.